# Need Help getting perl module DBD::mysql installed for bugzilla on RedHat

Tags: linux, redhat, perl, bugzilla, cpan

Hi everyone I am having some issues getting Bugzilla setup, I have the software on the server and am trying to get the pre-rec's setup. I am using RedHat 4.1.2-42.
I have all of the required perl modules save one:DBD::mysql

When I try:

```
sudo perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql
```

I get the following response(this is only an excerpt):

```
rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/lib64/mysql:/usr/lib64:/lib64" /usr/bin/perl myld gcc -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic dbdimp.o mysql.o -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so \
-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto \

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libssl.so when searching for -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libssl.a when searching for -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so] Error 1
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

I then tried the following:

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/lib64/mysql:/usr/lib64:/lib64" perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql
```

I get the same result.

I have also tried to install it using CPAN but also get the same result.
Right now I have DBD-mysql v3.0007 but need (v4.00)

Also when I try to install open ssl it says I have the latest version.
Does anyone know what I have to do to get this to work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

**After reading the response by gareth_bowles  I tried the following here is what I get:**

**yum:**

```
Package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version Nothing to do
```

**RPM 32bit:**

```
warning: perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el4.rf.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY,                                                          key ID 6b8d79e6
error: Failed dependencies:
        libmysqlclient.so.14 is needed by perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el4.rf.i386
        libmysqlclient.so.14(libmysqlclient_14) is needed by perl-DBD-mysql-4.00                                                         6-1.el4.rf.i386
```

**RPM 64bit:**

```
rpm -i perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
warning: perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKE                                                         Y, key ID 6b8d79e6
        file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Bundle                                                         /DBD/mysql.pm from install of perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64 conflicts wit                                                         h file from package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/my                                                         sql.pm from install of perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file                                                          from package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/my                                                         sql/GetInfo.pm from install of perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64 conflicts wi                                                         th file from package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/my                                                         sql/INSTALL.pod from install of perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64 conflicts w                                                         ith file from package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64
        file /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/D                                                         BD/mysql/mysql.so from install of perl-DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64 conflicts                                                          with file from package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64
        file /usr/share/man/man3/Bundle::DBD::mysql.3pm.gz from install of perl-                                                         DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-DBD-MySQL-                                                         3.0007-2.el5.x86_64
        file /usr/share/man/man3/DBD::mysql.3pm.gz from install of perl-DBD-mysq                                                         l-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2                                                         .el5.x86_64
        file /usr/share/man/man3/DBD::mysql::INSTALL.3pm.gz from install of perl                                                         -DBD-mysql-4.006-1.el5.rf.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-DBD-MySQL                                                         -3.0007-2.el5.x86_64
```

**After trying Make I get the following result:**

```
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so] Error 1
[root@walhoutlab DBD-mysql-4.010]# make install
rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/lib64/mysql:/usr/lib64:/lib64" /usr/bin/perl myld gcc  -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic dbdimp.o mysql.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so   \
           -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto   \

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libssl.so when searching for -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libssl.a when searching for -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth trying to install from an RPM instead of via CPAN:

```
yum install perl-DBD-mysql
```

This should resolve any missing dependencies that you have.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that did not work here is what I get:
Package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

The problem though is that I need version 4.0, and for some reason yum does not get it.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that; it means your base operating system version was released with an older version of DBD-MySQL.  It's possible to upgrade, but you're likeyl to have to build a bunch of dependencies from source if you take that route.